# How to use reform gem with two models that share identical column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the [Reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform/) gem and want to create 2 objects (an instance of Foo, and one of Bar) which both have a 'name' attribute:

```
class MarflarForm < Reform:Form
    include DSL
    include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord

    property :name, on: :foo
    property :name, on: :bar
end
```

But I cant do this for obvious reasons:

```
= simple_form_for @form do |f|
  = f.input :file
  = f.input :file
```

The only way I can think of getting round this is by renaming one of database columns to 'title'. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just simple, For achieve this goal please use:

```
class MarflarForm < Reform:Form
    include DSL
    include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord

    property :name, on: :foo
    property :name, on: :bar
end
```

and In the view

```
= simple_form_for @form do |f|
  = f.input "foo[name]"
  = f.input "bar[name]"
```

This avoid name collision.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the Reform gem, but it looks tome like you can call the properties whatever you want. So try

```
property :foo_file, on: :foo
property :baz_file, on: :baz
```

Then, on save, you'll just have to be responsible for mapping those properties back to the correct model attributes.

```
@form.save do |data, nested|
  @foo.file = nested[:foo_file]
  @baz.file = nested[:baz_file]
  # etc...
end
```

Does something like that work?